# Postgresql not listening on the correct port using service command

Tags: amazon-ec2, postgresql, port, service

In my `/var/lib/pgsql9/data/postgresql.conf` I added `port = 55434` and if I start Postgres with `/usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql9/data/` as the `postgres` user then Postgres is listening to the right port `lsof -i -nP`:

```
COMMAND    PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postgres 12127 postgres    3u  IPv4  49394      0t0  TCP *:55434 (LISTEN)
postgres 12127 postgres    4u  IPv6  49395      0t0  TCP *:55434 (LISTEN)
postgres 12127 postgres   10u  IPv4  49402      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57562->127.0.0.1:57562
postgres 12130 postgres   10u  IPv4  49402      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57562->127.0.0.1:57562
postgres 12131 postgres   10u  IPv4  49402      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57562->127.0.0.1:57562
postgres 12132 postgres   10u  IPv4  49402      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57562->127.0.0.1:57562
postgres 12133 postgres   10u  IPv4  49402      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57562->127.0.0.1:57562
postgres 12134 postgres   10u  IPv4  49402      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:57562->127.0.0.1:57562
```

But if I try with `service postgresql start` as `root`, then it listens to the default `5432`

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
postmaste 12256 postgres    3u  IPv4  49690      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
postmaste 12256 postgres    4u  IPv6  49691      0t0  TCP *:5432 (LISTEN)
postmaste 12256 postgres   10u  IPv4  49698      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:42404->127.0.0.1:42404
postmaste 12260 postgres   10u  IPv4  49698      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:42404->127.0.0.1:42404
postmaste 12261 postgres   10u  IPv4  49698      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:42404->127.0.0.1:42404
postmaste 12262 postgres   10u  IPv4  49698      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:42404->127.0.0.1:42404
postmaste 12263 postgres   10u  IPv4  49698      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:42404->127.0.0.1:42404
postmaste 12264 postgres   10u  IPv4  49698      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:42404->127.0.0.1:42404
```

I've noticed the difference in `COMMAND` (`postmaste` vs `postgres`) but I don't really know why running `service` doesn't read the `postgresql.conf` that I edited. I would have assumed `root` could read it. I would like to use `service` since I can easily set Postgres to run at boot with `chkconfig postgresql on`, but if I have to use `pg_ctrl` then I guess I'll have to add the start command in `/etc/rc.local` (anything wrong with this?).

This is on a `t1.micro` instance of 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2014.03 (latest as of writing). And running `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.7` (installed via `yum`).

I'm not very good with Linux so any help and tip is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: looks like service command uses different config file, or even different postgres location

Comment: Yep, check things like `/etc/default/postgresql`, `/etc/sysconfig/postgresql`, `/etc/postgresql`, etc, see if there's a config file that overrides the port. In general I strongly recommend *avoiding* Amazon's PostgreSQL packages, and using a well tested and established distribution like CentOS, RHEL, Ubuntu, or Debian that has proper packages from http://apt.postgresql.org/ or http://yum.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it turned out I didn't read the `postgres.conf` carefully enough. It read (in the comments):

```
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
# Note: In RHEL/Fedora installations, you can't set the port number here;
# adjust it in the service file instead.
```

So I find that the file to edit was `/etc/rc.d/init.d/postgresql` and I changed the port setting in the following lines:

```
# Set defaults for configuration variables
PGENGINE=/usr/bin
PGPORT=55434
PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql9/data
PGLOG=/var/lib/pgsql9/pgstartup.log
# Value to set as postmaster process's oom_adj
PG_OOM_ADJ=-17
```

Then I simply did `service postgresql restart` and it finally started listening on my `55434` port.